# Any way to change the subscription?

Tags: web3js, nodejs

I'm working with "web3.eth.subscribe" but when I've been running the script for 20-40 minutes, the script stops automatically. I think it's because it does an unsubscribe, that is, the subscription.id stops.

some help?

```
var subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('pendingTransactions', function(error, result){
    if (!error)
        //console.log(result);
})
.on("data", async function(transaction){
    console.log(transaction); //here stops 20-40 mins 
});

// unsubscribes the subscription
subscription.unsubscribe(function(error, success){
    if(success)
        console.log('Successfully unsubscribed!');
});
```

Comment: Can you share the code you are using?

Comment: add code, when .on("data", async function(transaction){
    console.log(transaction); //here stops
});

Comment: The code seems fine, I'd guess is something with the web3 provider or some network connectivity issue.